# how to give on press and on release simultaneously in actionscript

Tags: actionscript

I have the following code

```
on(press){
    gotoAndPlay(193);
}
on(release) {
    getURL("http://www.sumangalijewellers.com");
}
```

when I press button it have to play and go to the page

Comment: can't you simply write both the jobs in on press?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a few ways.

1. Just call both functions in a row.

   on(press){
     gotoAndPlay(193);
     getURL("http://www.sumangalijewellers.com");
   }
2. Wire up onRelease to onPress

   // this should wire up you onRelease to onPress.

   myButton.onRelease = myButton.onPress;